# Why won't Discord bot recognize commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot for a pokemon server, and I'm trying to make a command that will give the 'Gym Leader' role to another user. I try using the command, and using the test command, but there is no response in the server nor the shell.

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='b!', case_insensitive=True)

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event #works
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    channel = client.get_channel(697500755766018098)

@client.event #works
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to Pokémon Beast Ball!\n\nThis server utilizes Pokecord and Mewbot.\n\nSay \'pkhelp\' in the server to learn about Pokecord commands.\nSay \';help\' in the server to learn about Mewbot commands.'
    )

@bot.command() #doesn't work
async def test(ctx):
    print("test recieved")
    await ctx.send(ctx)

@bot.command(pass_context=True) #this is the command that really needs help
async def newleader(ctx: discord.User=None):
  print("command recieved")
  if not user:
    await ctx.send("Invalid")
    print("1")
  else:
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Gym Leader")
    role2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Purple UniTurtle Man")
    if role in ctx.author.roles or role2 in ctx.author.roles:
        print("2")
        await ctx.send(f'A new Gym Leader has been appointed')
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await bot.remove_roles(ctx.author, role)
    else:
        print("3")
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to use this command")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `bot` and `client` and your `client = discord.Client()` is stepping on your `bot = commands.Bot(...)` statement. Since you want to do commands and events you only use the `commands.Bot(...)` statement.

Remove the `client = discord.Client()` statement and change your `@client.event` decorators to `@bot.event`.

Also if you want to reference the command context in your test command update it with the ctx parameter `async def test(ctx):`.

That will get you started using your commands and entering `b1test` will now work.

Please note that the `case_insensitive=True` on the commands declaration refers to the command name and not the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check :

- bot connection → make a "on_connect" event (not exactly the same as "on_ready") to see if your bot successfully connect to your server (before receiving data from discord). If not, try to add your bot again to your server and check if all tokens are goods.
- bot permissions (if your bot have the right to write in channel, read messages from channels, manage roles) → if your bot cannot read messages, he can't read commands !
- role priority (you can't manage roles highers thant yours) → go to "server settings" > "roles" > put your bot role above the 'Gym Leader' role (or at the top of the list if you don't care).

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't actually what the selected answer suggests. There is probably no reason to use both `commands.Bot` and `discord.Client` but using both won't lead to that issue.

The issue is because you are only running the `client`, not the `bot`. You need to also run the `bot` instance if you want it to function.

If you are not trying to do something specific, then just using either `bot` or `client` will suffice anyway, so that part of the selected answer was helpful in avoiding the issue at least.